# using sequence in SQL loader

Tags: sql-loader

I have created table as

```
CREATE TABLE TEST2
(Seq varchar2(255 CHAR),
ID varchar2(255 CHAR),
NAME VARCHAR2 (255 CHAR),
DOB TIMESTAMP(3)
);
```

my control file is

```
load data
 infile 'C:\Users\sgujar\Documents\CDAR\test2.csv'
 append into table TEST2
 fields terminated by ","
 (ID,
NAME,
DOB "TO_TIMESTAMP (:DOB,  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')",
seq"TEST2_seq.nextval"
```

)

I am not able to use sequence in sql loader.

Can you please help

Comment: Please edit your question, with the error you are getting.

Comment: Hi I am not getting any error. sqlldr command is executing without error but no rows are getting inserted.

Comment: Yes I have checked the log file and it shows the rows which are not loaded. If I remove sequence then this is working fine.

Comment: Very interesting issue you have found here! I sql-traced the loading and, clearly, when direct load is used, there is no sequence value fetch executed internally. For "direct=false" the sequence works as a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a particularly pretty solution, it does what you ask:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION get_test2_seq RETURN INTEGER
IS
BEGIN
    RETURN TEST2_seq.nextval;
END;
/
```

And then your control file would be

```
load data
 infile 'C:\Users\sgujar\Documents\CDAR\test2.csv'
 append into table TEST2
 fields terminated by ","
(
    ID,
    NAME,
    DOB "TO_TIMESTAMP (:DOB,  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')",
    SEQ "get_test2_seq()"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for sure
options (DIRECT=TRUE,readsize=4096000,bindsize=4096000,skip=1,errors=1,rows=50000)
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8 LENGTH SEMANTICS CHARACTER
INFILE     /path/test.csv'

BADFILE         '/path/file.bad'

INSERT INTO  TABLE test_table

FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'TRAILING NULLCOLS

(
Col1  sequence(1,1),
Col2       constant "N",
)